# Unable to click on filter on grid in selenium

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am giving the code below where I need to click on the filter icon. please help me out

I have tried using the code as

```
WebElement element1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell\"]/a[1]/span"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element1);
```

```html
<th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" data-field="Status" data-index="8" data-title="Status" scope="col" style="overflow: visible; white-space: normal;font-weight: bold;width:70px; vertical-align:top;" data-role="columnsorter" id="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell" aria-describedby="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell"> 
    <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="k-icon k-filter"></span>
    </a> 
    <a class="k-link" href="/tracs/tracs/LaborOps/AutoLaborOps_Read?grdAutoLaborOp‌​s-sort=Status-asc" tabindex="-1">Status</a>
</th>
```

Comment: <th class="k-header k-filterable k-with-icon" data-field="Status" data-index="8" data-title="Status" scope="col" style="overflow: visible; white-space: normal;font-weight: bold;width:70px;
vertical-align:top;" data-role="columnsorter" id="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell" aria-describedby="grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell">
    <a class="k-grid-filter" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1"><span class="k-icon k-filter"></span></a>
    <a class="k-link" href="/tracs/tracs/LaborOps/AutoLaborOps_Read?grdAutoLaborOps-sort=Status-asc" tabindex="-1">Status</a></th>

Comment: Welcome to stack! Please put relevant code to your question in the actual question and not the comments. Formatting it as code would also help to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click `<span>` element directly or `<th>` class preceding `<span>` element.

SPAN:

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class*='filter']")).click()`

It basically means "Find `<span>` element which attribute `class` CONTAINS `filter`

TH:

Your code is almost correct. The line `//*[@id=\"grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell\"]` contains backslashes which tells java NOT to parse `"`. Which leads to following xpath `@id=grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell`. You should use single quote like this:

`//*[@id='grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell']`

or use cssSelector

`driver.findElement(By.id("grdAutoLaborOps_active_cell")).click();`

Comment: Hi Rafal, thanks for the response .........this works  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class*='filter']")).click(); but it is clicking on the first column filter of the grid  .The filter that i wanted selenuim code to click is on the 10 th column of the grid ...

Comment: Hi @Latha
Can you post some more code to your question? We can figure this out. Add HTML code for 1st and 10th column